# What's the translation of "stablecoin" in French?

Tags: traduction, terminologie, anglicismes, finance

A stablecoin [is a](https://hedera.com/learning/tokens/what-is-a-stablecoin):

> digital asset that remains stable in value against a pegged external traditional asset class.

What's the translation of "stablecoin" in French?

Google translate and DeepL didn't help.

Comment: Une coin indexée.

Answer (score 2):

Often the anglicism *un stablecoin* or *SC* is used.  However Wikipédia uses  [cryptomonnaie stable](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptomonnaie_stable)

> Une cryptomonnaie stable[1](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptomonnaie_stable) (en anglais : stablecoin) est une cryptomonnaie dont le prix est arrimé à une autre cryptomonnaie, à une monnaie fiduciaire ou à un produit négocié en bourse (comme les métaux précieux ou les métaux industriels).

In [Vocabulaire de l'économie](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/jorf/id/JORFTEXT000045062449) from legifrance.gouv.fr, the prescription is given for *cyberjeton indexé* instead and to avoid other translations:

> cyberjeton indexé
>
>  Domaine : Finance-Économie générale.
>
>  Définition : Cyberjeton dont la valeur est fixée en référence à une monnaie, à un panier de monnaies, ou, plus généralement, à un portefeuille d'actifs.
>
>  Note : On trouve aussi, dans le langage professionnel, les termes « jeton stable » et « cryptomonnaie stable », qui sont déconseillés.
>
>  Voir aussi : cyberjeton, cybermonnaie.
>
>  Équivalent étranger : asset-referenced token, stablecoin.

> cybermonnaie, n.f. Domaine : Finance-Informatique/Internet. Définition
> : Ensemble de cyberjetons de même nature pouvant servir à des
> paiements, à l'instar d'une monnaie ayant cours légal.

Clearly they do not advise *jeton stable* or *cryptomonnaie stable*.

But many sources just use *stablecoin* (n.m.), as seen at Coinbase:

> Un stablecoin est une monnaie numérique adossée à une valeur-refuge «
> stable » comme le dollar américain ou l'or.

Cryptoast.fr uses *stablecoin* and gives *monnaie stable* (n.f.) to explain the anglicism.

> Un stablecoin, ou monnaie stable en français, est un type de cryptomonnaie qui tente d'apporter de la stabilité à ce marché très volatil.

France 24 used quotes around it in an [article](https://amp.france24.com/fr/%25C3%25A9co-tech/20220219-cryptomonnaies-les-stablecoins-nouveau-d%25C3%25A9fi-%25C3%25A0-la-stabilit%25C3%25A9-financi%25C3%25A8re-mondiale) dated February 2022.

> Cryptomonnaies : les "stablecoins", nouveau défi à la stabilité financière ...

Finally to avoid the anglicism, [Numerama](https://www.numerama.com/tech/831641-ne-dites-plus-stablecoin-mais-cyberjeton-indexe-en-bon-francais.html/amp) says: *Ne dites plus stablecoin, mais « cyberjeton indexé », en bon français* :

> On croise également de plus en plus le terme de « stablecoin » ou, plus rare, « asset-referenced token ». En français, cela se traduit par « cyberjeton indexé » ou bien « jeton indexé »